# Converting path into file and php get

Tags: .htaccess

So I have some code  code to change this url:

```
site.com/example
```

to:

```
site.com/example.php
```

Heres the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.php [L]
```

But I was wondering how I could change this:

```
site.com/example/foo
```

To this:

```
site.com/example.php?p=foo
```

But have it so the /foo part isnt required for it to work.
Anyone know how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to 2 rules for this, replace your the code you provided with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/*$ /$1.php?p=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/*$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Sorry for having to ask it here, I just really needed help.